# JavaScript Resize, Drag, Snap with custom window/div size

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, drag

I'm trying to figure out a way to resize/drag/snap a div element within a custom window/div size, not just the entire window. I had found this code here https://codepen.io/zz85/pen/gbOoVP which is exactly the functionality I'm looking for but I cannot figure out a way to adapt it to a custom bounding size. Currently it just takes the main windows bounds. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!
Here is the main Javascript code that I had found:

```
"use strict";

// Minimum resizable area
var minWidth = 60;
var minHeight = 40;

// Thresholds
var FULLSCREEN_MARGINS = -10;
var MARGINS = 4;

// End of what's configurable.
var clicked = null;
var onRightEdge, onBottomEdge, onLeftEdge, onTopEdge;

var rightScreenEdge, bottomScreenEdge;

var preSnapped;

var b, x, y;

var redraw = false;

var pane = document.getElementById('pane');
var ghostpane = document.getElementById('ghostpane');

function setBounds(element, x, y, w, h) {
    element.style.left = x + 'px';
    element.style.top = y + 'px';
    element.style.width = w + 'px';
    element.style.height = h + 'px';
}

function hintHide() {
  setBounds(ghostpane, b.left, b.top, b.width, b.height);
  ghostpane.style.opacity = 0;

  // var b = ghostpane.getBoundingClientRect();
  // ghostpane.style.top = b.top + b.height / 2;
  // ghostpane.style.left = b.left + b.width / 2;
  // ghostpane.style.width = 0;
  // ghostpane.style.height = 0;
}


// Mouse events
pane.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onUp);

// Touch events 
pane.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchDown);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
document.addEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd);


function onTouchDown(e) {
  onDown(e.touches[0]);
  e.preventDefault();
}

function onTouchMove(e) {
  onMove(e.touches[0]);     
}

function onTouchEnd(e) {
  if (e.touches.length ==0) onUp(e.changedTouches[0]);
}

function onMouseDown(e) {
  onDown(e);
  e.preventDefault();
}

function onDown(e) {
  calc(e);

  var isResizing = onRightEdge || onBottomEdge || onTopEdge || onLeftEdge;

  clicked = {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    cx: e.clientX,
    cy: e.clientY,
    w: b.width,
    h: b.height,
    isResizing: isResizing,
    isMoving: !isResizing && canMove(),
    onTopEdge: onTopEdge,
    onLeftEdge: onLeftEdge,
    onRightEdge: onRightEdge,
    onBottomEdge: onBottomEdge
  };
}

function canMove() {
  return x > 0 && x < b.width && y > 0 && y < b.height
  && y < 30;
}

function calc(e) {
  b = pane.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = e.clientX - b.left;
  y = e.clientY - b.top;

  onTopEdge = y < MARGINS;
  onLeftEdge = x < MARGINS;
  onRightEdge = x >= b.width - MARGINS;
  onBottomEdge = y >= b.height - MARGINS;

  rightScreenEdge = window.innerWidth - MARGINS;
  bottomScreenEdge = window.innerHeight - MARGINS;
}

var e;

function onMove(ee) {
  calc(ee);

  e = ee;

  redraw = true;

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (!redraw) return;

  redraw = false;

  if (clicked && clicked.isResizing) {

    if (clicked.onRightEdge) pane.style.width = Math.max(x, minWidth) + 'px';
    if (clicked.onBottomEdge) pane.style.height = Math.max(y, minHeight) + 'px';

    if (clicked.onLeftEdge) {
      var currentWidth = Math.max(clicked.cx - e.clientX  + clicked.w, minWidth);
      if (currentWidth > minWidth) {
        pane.style.width = currentWidth + 'px';
        pane.style.left = e.clientX + 'px'; 
      }
    }

    if (clicked.onTopEdge) {
      var currentHeight = Math.max(clicked.cy - e.clientY  + clicked.h, minHeight);
      if (currentHeight > minHeight) {
        pane.style.height = currentHeight + 'px';
        pane.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';  
      }
    }

    hintHide();

    return;
  }

  if (clicked && clicked.isMoving) {

    if (b.top < FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.left < FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.right > window.innerWidth - FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.bottom > window.innerHeight - FULLSCREEN_MARGINS) {
      // hintFull();
      setBounds(ghostpane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else if (b.top < MARGINS) {
      // hintTop();
      setBounds(ghostpane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight / 2);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else if (b.left < MARGINS) {
      // hintLeft();
      setBounds(ghostpane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else if (b.right > rightScreenEdge) {
      // hintRight();
      setBounds(ghostpane, window.innerWidth / 2, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else if (b.bottom > bottomScreenEdge) {
      // hintBottom();
      setBounds(ghostpane, 0, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth / 2);
      ghostpane.style.opacity = 0.2;
    } else {
      hintHide();
    }

    if (preSnapped) {
      setBounds(pane,
        e.clientX - preSnapped.width / 2,
        e.clientY - Math.min(clicked.y, preSnapped.height),
        preSnapped.width,
        preSnapped.height
      );
      return;
    }

    // moving
    pane.style.top = (e.clientY - clicked.y) + 'px';
    pane.style.left = (e.clientX - clicked.x) + 'px';

    return;
  }

  // This code executes when mouse moves without clicking

  // style cursor
  if (onRightEdge && onBottomEdge || onLeftEdge && onTopEdge) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'nwse-resize';
  } else if (onRightEdge && onTopEdge || onBottomEdge && onLeftEdge) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'nesw-resize';
  } else if (onRightEdge || onLeftEdge) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'ew-resize';
  } else if (onBottomEdge || onTopEdge) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'ns-resize';
  } else if (canMove()) {
    pane.style.cursor = 'move';
  } else {
    pane.style.cursor = 'default';
  }
}

animate();

function onUp(e) {
  calc(e);

  if (clicked && clicked.isMoving) {
    // Snap
    var snapped = {
      width: b.width,
      height: b.height
    };

    if (b.top < FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.left < FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.right > window.innerWidth - FULLSCREEN_MARGINS || b.bottom > window.innerHeight - FULLSCREEN_MARGINS) {
      // hintFull();
      setBounds(pane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else if (b.top < MARGINS) {
      // hintTop();
      setBounds(pane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight / 2);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else if (b.left < MARGINS) {
      // hintLeft();
      setBounds(pane, 0, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else if (b.right > rightScreenEdge) {
      // hintRight();
      setBounds(pane, window.innerWidth / 2, 0, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else if (b.bottom > bottomScreenEdge) {
      // hintBottom();
      setBounds(pane, 0, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth / 2);
      preSnapped = snapped;
    } else {
      preSnapped = null;
    }

    hintHide();

  }

  clicked = null;

}
```